# Can STM32 Discovery differentiate between short and long push of a button

Tags: c, stm32f4discovery

It would come in handy if I could implement long and short button push in my project. I am using STM32F4 Discovery Kit and program it in C. I have prepared one pin as an external input, I modified the interrupt handler.

schema:
[image]

I set it to trigger at falling and rising, for now. I see no obvious way how to detect long and short pushes. Is there any way?

Comment: I would not use edge interrupts for buttons, they are way to bouncy. Use polling and then it is also easier to figure out the timing.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: @r_ahlskog: Using an interrupt to detect an edge is fine, but of course it's not sufficient.

Comment: @ThomasJager: It is nothing else than a software question. But it's way too broad.

Comment: The hardware has all provisions to do that. Read the datasheet, and more practice about embedded software would also not hurt.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite yes, it can be fine. In practice I have found that unless the "button" is another microcontroller or something with clean sharp transitions that polling is easier to reason about.

Comment: @r_ahlskog: I'm talking about push buttons. If you ever have to develop an energy-critical device, you will change your mind. Or if you move to event-base programming without polling. Unfortunately, I've met too many people who think only black and white and can't combine multiple techniques.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite: sounds fair enough, most of what I built lately seems to have been attached to things that sink 100W for fun and the MCU power consumption was a rounding error. Yeah gotta pick the right tool for the job, and then it helps to not have a toolbox of hammers. I see your point.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to start timer as soon as the button is pressed stop the timer after button is released. Based on the number of ticks elapsed in the timer, you can take the correct action, However you need to decided the threshold number of ticks to differentiate between long press and short press.

As an improvement to above suggestion. Instead of configuring the pin to which to push button is connected as GPIO, You can Configure as IO interrupt source. This method is helpful for you to solve denouncing issue also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's well doable, here is a solution in the Interrupt handler on an STM32.

Global vars:

```
static uint32_t lastUserButtonI = 700;
static uint32_t lastUserButtonRisingI = 700;
static uint32_t lastUserButtonFallingI = 700;
```

In `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback()`:

```
  uint32_t now = HAL_GetTick();
  uint8_t rising = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Button_GPIO_Port, pButton);
  if ((lastEdge == rising) ||
      (rising == 0 && ((now - lastUserButtonFallingI) <= 200)) ||
      (rising == 1 && ((now - lastUserButtonRisingI) <= 200))) {
    DBG_PRINTF("CANCELLING, %u\n", (uint)now);
  } else {
    if (rising == 1) {
      DEBUG_MSG("RISING\n");
      lastUserButtonRisingI = now;
    } else {
      DEBUG_MSG("FALLING\n");
      lastUserButtonFallingI = now;
    }
    DBG_PRINTF("Button Press Gesture, %u\n", (uint)now);
    uint32_t diff = lastUserButtonFallingI - lastUserButtonRisingI;
    if (rising == 0 && diff >= 10 && diff <= 500) {
      // Single press
      DEBUG_MSG("SINGLE PRESS\n");
    }
    if (rising == 0 && diff >= 2000 && diff <= 8000) {
      // Long press
      DEBUG_MSG("LONG PRESS\n");
    }
  }
  lastEdge = rising;
  lastUserButtonI = now;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of EXTI interrupts are very bad for the buttons. You should use timer interrupt and periodically check the state of the button. Even if you have a capacitor it may not be enough with the ageing button for debouncing.

You can see my button library - long, short and double click, any number of buttons

https://www.diymat.co.uk/arm-three-function-click-double-and-long-click-button-library-timer-interrupt-driven/

Comment: EXTI are fine for push buttons. They are also the way if you have to conserve as much power as possible. No need for a capacitor either (not that a small one hurts, but it's more interesting for EMI than to debounce).

Comment: @toohonestforthissite EXTI are not buttons friendly. Waking up is something different - wake from the button, then timer

Comment: Why are EXTI interrupts bad?  Because debouncing is required?  It seems that polling would be the worse, especially if device sleeping is desired.

Comment: 'You should use timer interrupt and periodically check the state of the button'.  To me that means polling.

Answer (score 0):

1.I wanted to create a button reading structure that will not interrupt both the main return flow and the long and short push states. Is not that a button pressed for that? BT_User_State variable holding the dataset, button pressed long, pressed short? I have defined two separate BT_User_Flag_ShortPress and BT_User_Flag_LongPress variables holding the data, plus a BT_User_Time variable that will hold for the duration.

```
typedef enum{
Flag_Reset,
Flag_Set
}   Button_Flag;

typedef enum{
Button_Released,
Button_Pressed
}   Button_State;

Button_State    BT_User_State = Button_Released;
Button_Flag     BT_User_Flag_ShortPress = Flag_Reset;
Button_Flag     BT_User_Flag_LongPress = Flag_Reset;
uint16_t        BT_User_Time = 0;
```

2.There is also a Timer every 1ms. After you have done this, the Timer overflows :

```
if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BT_User_GPIO_Port, BT_User_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_SET)
{
   BT_User_State = Button_Pressed;
   BT_User_Time++;
} 
else 
{
   if(BT_User_Time >= 750)
{
    BT_User_Flag_LongPress = Flag_Set;
} 
else if (BT_User_Time >= 50) 
{
    BT_User_Flag_ShortPress = Flag_Set;
}
BT_User_Time = 0;
BT_User_State = Button_Released;
}
```

3.If the button is pressed while the cut is occurring, I changed the button status to Printed and added the variable 1 that holds the duration.
If the button is not pressed when the cut occurs, I checked the variable holding the value first, starting with the large value and set the necessary flags. I finally reset the variable holding the duration and changed the button state to Dropped.

In the main loop :

```
    if(BT_User_Flag_ShortPress == Flag_Set && BT_User_State == Button_Released)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD_Blue_GPIO_Port, LD_Blue_Pin);
        BT_User_Flag_ShortPress = Flag_Reset;
    }

    if(BT_User_Flag_LongPress == Flag_Set && BT_User_State == Button_Released)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD_Red_GPIO_Port, LD_Red_Pin);
        BT_User_Flag_LongPress = Flag_Reset;
    }
```